# Jfrog Pipeline - how I can get the committer name/login on the merge to master branch

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

In the pipeline's step, how do I get the name of the committer

I have tried to use

```
res_<resource name>_committerLogin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `res_<resource_name>_lastAuthorLogin` environment variable instead.

Please refer to this documentation of [GitRepo Environment Variables](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/GitRepo) for more information.